# Get all countries in comboBox

Tags: c#, combobox, windows-store-apps

I want to fill the ComboBox with all the country names list by using

```
Using System.Globalization
Using System.Collections
```

here is my XAML coding for the ComboBox

```
<ComboBox x:Name="countryComboBox" Width="300"/>
```

In the C# coding I have add button. Here is that code, and I want to get the country from the ComboBox and store it in the MySql database. How can I do that?

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string Query = @"INSERT INTO `bcasdb`.`tbl_student`
                         (`reg_id`,
                          `std_fname`,
                          `std_lname`,
                          `tbl_batch_batch_id`,
                          `gender`) 
                         VALUES (@regId, @fName, @lName, @bID, @gender, @country)";
        //This is command class which will handle the query and connection object.
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(BCASApp.DataModel.DB_CON.connection);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regId", this.regIDInput.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fName", this.fnameInput.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lName", this.lnameInput.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bID", this.batchIDInput.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender",this.maleRadioButton);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        successmsgBox();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        errormsgBox();
    }
}
```

Comment: its complicated and dont understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code to get all Countries:**

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class LocalesRetrievalException : Exception
{
    public LocalesRetrievalException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }
}

#region Windows API

private delegate bool EnumLocalesProcExDelegate(
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]String lpLocaleString,
   LocaleType dwFlags, int lParam);

[DllImport(@"kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern bool EnumSystemLocalesEx(EnumLocalesProcExDelegate pEnumProcEx,
   LocaleType dwFlags, int lParam, IntPtr lpReserved);

private enum LocaleType : uint
{
    LocaleAll = 0x00000000,             // Enumerate all named based locales
    LocaleWindows = 0x00000001,         // Shipped locales and/or replacements for them
    LocaleSupplemental = 0x00000002,    // Supplemental locales only
    LocaleAlternateSorts = 0x00000004,  // Alternate sort locales
    LocaleNeutralData = 0x00000010,     // Locales that are "neutral" (language only, region data is default)
    LocaleSpecificData = 0x00000020,    // Locales that contain language and region data
}

#endregion

public enum CultureTypes : uint
{
    SpecificCultures = LocaleType.LocaleSpecificData,
    NeutralCultures = LocaleType.LocaleNeutralData,
    AllCultures = LocaleType.LocaleWindows
}

public static List<CultureInfo> GetCultures(CultureTypes cultureTypes)
{
    List<CultureInfo> cultures = new List<CultureInfo>();
    EnumLocalesProcExDelegate enumCallback = (locale, flags, lParam) =>
    {
        try
        {
            cultures.Add(new CultureInfo(locale));
        }
        catch (CultureNotFoundException)
        {
            // This culture is not supported by .NET (not happened so far)
            // Must be ignored.
        }
        return true;
    };

    if (EnumSystemLocalesEx(enumCallback, (LocaleType)cultureTypes, 0, (IntPtr)0) == false)
    {
        int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        throw new LocalesRetrievalException("Win32 error " + errorCode + " while trying to get the Windows locales");
    }

    // Add the two neutral cultures that Windows misses 
    // (CultureInfo.GetCultures adds them also):
    if (cultureTypes == CultureTypes.NeutralCultures || cultureTypes == CultureTypes.AllCultures)
    {
        cultures.Add(new CultureInfo("zh-CHS"));
        cultures.Add(new CultureInfo("zh-CHT"));
    }

    return cultures;
}

public static List<string> GetCountries()
{
    List<CultureInfo> cultures = GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
    List<string> countries = new List<string>();

    foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultures)
    {
        RegionInfo region = new RegionInfo(culture.Name);

        if (!(countries.Contains(region.EnglishName)))
        {
            countries.Add(region.EnglishName);
        }
    }

    return countries;
}
```

**How to use this code:**

You just need to call method `GetCountries`:

```
comboBoxCountries.ItemsSource = GetCountries();
```

Reference: [Replacement for CultureInfo.GetCultures in .NET Windows Store apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485626/replacement-for-cultureinfo-getcultures-in-net-windows-store-apps)

Answer (score 4):

This method will return you **ordered** list of all countries:

```
public static List<string> GetAllCountrysNames()
{
    CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);

    return cultures
            .Select(cult => (new RegionInfo(cult.LCID)).DisplayName)
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(q => q) 
            .ToList();
}
```

Also you can replace `DisplayName` to `EnglishName` if you need.

---

```
countryComboBox.Items.AddRange(GetAllCountrysNames());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can fill the Combobox like this,

add `using System.Globalization`

Set the Combobox ItemsSource like this,

```
countryComboBox.ItemsSource = GetCountryList();

public static List<string> GetCountryList()
{
    List<string> cultureList = new List<string>();

    CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);

    foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultures)
    {
        RegionInfo region = new RegionInfo(culture.LCID);

        if (!(cultureList.Contains(region.EnglishName)))
        {
            cultureList.Add(region.EnglishName);
        }
    }
    return cultureList;
}
```

You can just get the selectedItem and pass it with the query,

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", this.countryComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

**EDIT:**
You have mentioned it is for Windows Store App, Check this link.How to load countryes

[`Replacement for CultureInfo.GetCultures in .NET Windows Store apps`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485626/replacement-for-cultureinfo-getcultures-in-net-windows-store-apps)

If not, you have to write a custom way to load the countries from the database.

Comment: so where is the country list?

Comment: there are errors on **countryComboBox.ItemsSource = GetCountryList();** and  **CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);** and **LCID**

Comment: Did you add the namespace? am not getting any error

Comment: yes i did add and this is windows store app using xaml and c#

Comment: I checked it on the `winform`. I think there may be a problem with bindings. @sahanYugantha You tagged question with `WPF` and now you're saying its an store app?

Comment: yeah it was happened accidently sorry about that, please help me to do this. now these are the available errors `CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);` and `LCID`

Comment: @sahanYugantha Yes it is not available for windows store app, you need to go for some other alternatives, please check my modified answer.