# Do address lookup using culture and language of current country of W10 device

Tags: c#, localization, uwp, bing-maps, uwp-maps

I am developing a UWP app using the Maps control that allows a user to plan a route by adding waypoints on the map using various methods such as  clicking on the UWP Map control.  One of the ways I want to allow a user to add a  waypoint or location is to search by actual address.  I use the BING Maps REST services code below but if I don't supply the language and culture of where the app is currently being used it always returns American addresses first which are clearly no use to users not in the USA (Yes Microsoft, some of us actually live outside the USA - shock, horror!). I discovered if I supplied the language-culture string such as "en-AU" for Australia then it will search Australian addresses first, and this works really well.

```
public async Task<List<WayPoint>> FindAddress(string address)
    {
        List<WayPoint> matchingWaypoints = new List<WayPoint>();

        //Create a Geocode request to submit to the BING Maps REST service.
        var request = new GeocodeRequest()
        {
            Query = address.Trim(),
            Culture = "en-AU",  //HOW CAN I GET THIS FROM THE DEVICE'S CURRENT LOCATION???
            IncludeIso2 = true,
            IncludeNeighborhood = true,
            MaxResults = 10,
            BingMapsKey = MapServiceToken
        };

        //Process the request by using the BING Maps REST services.
        var response = await ServiceManager.GetResponseAsync(request);

        if (response != null &&
            response.ResourceSets != null &&
            response.ResourceSets.Length > 0 &&
            response.ResourceSets[0].Resources != null &&
            response.ResourceSets[0].Resources.Length > 0)
        {
            int wpNumber = 0;
            foreach (BingMapsRESTToolkit.Location loc in response.ResourceSets[0].Resources)
                matchingWaypoints.Add(new WayPoint(wpNumber++, loc.Address.FormattedAddress, loc.Point.Coordinates[0], loc.Point.Coordinates[1]));               
        }

        return matchingWaypoints;
    }
```

So what I obviously want to do is derive this string based on the device's current location (i.e: country) NOT from the device's region settings.  So for example if someone is using the app the USA I want to specify en-US, if they're in New Zealand it would be en-NZ, if in France it would be "fr-FR" etc.  Does anyone know how I could do this?   All the stuff I've read about localisation uses the device settings NOT the current physical location so I'm still trying to work out how to do it.

If anyone can help out I'd really appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is an official sample of how to get location at https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Geolocation

This will return the latitude and longitude. You can then use a different [Bing API to get the country based on that lat/long](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ff701710.aspx).

This will give you a country name. With this you can lookup against a pre-generated list of codes to country names (created with `CultureInfo.GetCultures()` on your machine) or you could look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12491918/1755) for a way of doing this at runtime as `GetCultures()` isn't supported in UWP.

Using the Regional settings is simpler but if you want to use the actual location then this is the way to go. For devices where access to location isn't available then regional settings could be a good back up.

Another approach would be one of various public APIs which will give you information such as location based on IP address. This also isn't perfect though due to the use of proxies in different countries, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply Matt but I worked out how to do it with the help of the Bing Maps forum.  Instead of using the REST API am using the FindLocationsAsync call as part of the UWP Map API passing in the address, the local geopoint to use a starting reference (aka a 'hint' location) and the max number of matches to return... here's the code I used which works perfectly. (Note that WayPoint is an object from my model to store various info about a waypoint on the route.)

```
public async Task<List<WayPoint>> FindAddress(string address)
    {
        List<WayPoint> matchingWaypoints = new List<WayPoint>();

        // Use current location as a query hint so nearest addresses are returned.
        BasicGeoposition queryHint = new BasicGeoposition();
        queryHint.Latitude = this.CurrentLocation.Position.Latitude;
        queryHint.Longitude = this.CurrentLocation.Position.Longitude;
        Geopoint hintPoint = new Geopoint(queryHint);

        MapLocationFinderResult result =
           await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAsync(address.Trim(), hintPoint, 5);

        // If the query returns results, store in collection of WayPoint objects.
        string addresses = "";
        if (result.Status == MapLocationFinderStatus.Success)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (MapLocation res in result.Locations)
            {
                matchingWaypoints.Add(new WayPoint(i++, res.Address.FormattedAddress, res.Point.Position.Latitude, res.Point.Position.Longitude));
            }
        }
        return matchingWaypoints;
    }
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this won't do exactly what you asked. The UWP Finder API will always use the OS display language to search. The OS display language may not match the language of the country the user is currently in, which is what you were asking for.

Comment: Thanks Duncan, but I think you need to re-read my original post.  I did not ask for results in the local language - all I wanted was the culture & language string to seed the search so I got results for the local area/country first rather than US addresses.  The FindLocationsAsync actually does *exactly* what I asked.